# Copying Dynamic Range into a Different Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to copy and paste a dynamic range from one workbook to another in order to refresh an existing dashboard.

I've developed the code below, but continue to get error notifications on the italicized portion below:

```
Sub TransferData()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\file1.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\file2.xlsx")
    Set StartCell = Range("A1")    

    finalrow = x.Sheets("Worksheet Name").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'Counts
    FinalColumn = x.Sheets("Worksheet Name").Cells(1,
    Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    *x.Sheets("Worksheet Name").Range(StartCell, Cells(FinalRow,
    FinalColumn)).Copy*
    y.Sheets("Worksheet Name").Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(FinalRow,
    FinalColumn)).Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows.Count` is not being fully qualified with a `Worksheet` and neither is `Columns.Count` or `Cells` references. You need to fully qualify your Ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Could you help explain what you mean by qualify the ranges? I'm new to the world of VBA. If I have a bit more context I think I could run with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the worksheet, which is the "parent" of Cells as well. Like this:

```
With x.Sheets("Worksheet Name")
    .Range(StartCell, .Cells(finalrow, FinalColumn)).Copy
End With

With y.Sheets("Worksheet Name")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 7)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Comment: I've adjusted the code with the recommendations you included above but the following line is resulting in an 'Application-defined or object-defined error:                                                                                                                             With x.Sheets("sheets")
    .Range(StartCell, .Cells(FinalRow, FinalColumn)).Copy
End With

With y.Sheets("sheets")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 17), .Cells(FinalRow, FinalColumn)).Paste
End With

End Sub